# Proving $E(X|\mathscr{F})=E(X)$ when $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathscr{F}$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$ be a probability space and $X\in\mathscr{L}_1(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$ a random variable on that space. Let $\mathscr{F}\subset\mathscr{A}$ be a sigma-algebra.
>   If $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathscr{F}$ are independent,then $E(X|\mathscr{F})=E(X)$

Proof:
Trivially, $E(X)$ is measurable with respect to $\mathscr{F}$. Let $A\in\mathscr{F}$. Then $X$ and $\mathbb{1}_A$ are independent; hence $E(E(X|\mathscr{F})\mathbb{1}_A)=E(X\mathbb{1}_A)=E(X)E(\mathbb{1}_A)$

I am not understanding how this equality $E(E(X|\mathscr{F})\mathbb{1}_A)=E(X)E(\mathbb{1}_A)$ relates to $E(X|\mathscr{F})=E(X)$.

**Question**:

How do I get to the initial expression $E(X|\mathscr{F})=E(X)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recall that $Z = E[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$ almost surely if and only if $Z$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and for every $A \in \mathcal{F}$ we have that $E[Z1_A] = E[X1_A]$.

Here you have, for $A \in \mathcal{F}$
$$E[X1_A] = E[X] E[1_A] = E[E[X]1_A]$$
and hence $E[X] = E[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$.